# What are the premier Cricket competitions and leagues in the world?

Tags: cricket, participation

Over the last few years I've started to pay a bit more attention to Cricket, but I'm far removed from the culture and don't have much of an understanding of it.

So the question is:

If a person was an aspiring Cricket player in any given place in the world, which league or leagues would they dream of playing in, and which tournaments would they dream of winning?

Answer (score 4):

Bottom line is that the league which *pays* the most (by a significant margin) is the [Indian Premier League](http://www.iplt20.com/). If you think that T20 cricket is the "most important" form of cricket, then the IPL is where you want to be.

For 50 over cricket, the most important tournament is the [World Cup](http://www.icc-cricket.com/cricket-world-cup/index.html), closely followed by the [Champions Trophy](https://www.icc-cricket.com/champions-trophy). For Test cricket, there is no single tournament, so it's a question of playing for your country - for English or Australian players, the [Ashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ashes) are definitely the premier rivalry. For other countries, it's less clear, although a lot of players would say that playing at [Lord's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s) is a highlight.

Comment: Thanks. Then I can infer that the T20 World Cup is regarded as important by those who like T20? Is T20 what most people who are into the sport go for?

Comment: Umm, yeah, I forgot the T20 World Cup. I'll work that in. T20 is the bright shiny new thing in cricket, and can be very polarising: some people think it's a brilliant, exciting, short form of the game, others think it's just slogging without any of the subtlety of "proper" cricket.

Comment: It sounds like the sport is fairly splintered without the reach and standardisation of something like soccer. I'm assuming then, that it's really only popular in and around South Asia.

Comment: Cricket is popular in most of the former British Empire: England, Australia, New Zealand, India/Pakistan/Bangladesh/Sri Lanka, West Indies, South Africa & Zimbabwe are the Test-playing countries.